# Inferring observation time from a Brownian motion

Tags: brownian-motion, statistical-inference, bayesian

This might be a bit lengthy question. So let me proceed in steps.

**General description:** I have some observations, based on which I want to infer their occurring time.

**Specific setting:** Let $W(t)$ be a Brownian motion.
I have an observation $X$ defined as
$$X = BW(\delta) + (1-B)W(2\delta),$$
where $B$ is a Bernoulli draw with success rate $\frac{1}{2}$ and is independent of $W(t)$; and $\delta>0$ is some constant observation latency.

In words, the above is meant to capture the setting that I do not know when the observation $X$ occurred:
It might have occurred at time $t=\delta$ or at time $t=2\delta$, equally likely.

So given the observation $X$, I can infer something about the time of its occurrence: By Bayesian rule,
$$\mathbb{P}(B=1|X) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(B=1)\mathbb{P}(X|B=1)}{\mathbb{P}(B=1)\mathbb{P}(X|B=1)+\mathbb{P}(B=0)\mathbb{P}(X|B=0)}
= \frac{\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{P}(W(\delta)=X)}{\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{P}(W(\delta)=X)+\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{P}(W(2\delta)=X)}.
$$
Given that $W(t)$ is a Brownian motion, $W(\delta)$ and $W(2\delta)$ are normally distributed with respective densities
$$\mathbb{P}(W(\delta)=X) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\delta}}e^{-X^2/(2\delta)}$$
and
$$\mathbb{P}(W(2\delta)=X) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi\delta}}e^{-X^2/(4\delta)}.$$
So the above translates to a function of the density ratio
$$\mathbb{P}(B=1|X) = \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}e^{X^2/(4\delta)}},
$$
which is decreasing in the magnitude of $|X|$.
That is, the more extreme $X$ realizes to be, the less likely it comes from the early $W(\delta)$.
This makes sense as $W(\delta)$ is less volatile than $W(2\delta)$.

Next I want to consider what happens when $\delta\downarrow0$, i.e., when the gap between the timing of the observation asymptotically vanishes.
**Intuitively**, when $\delta\downarrow0$, $W(\delta)=W(2\delta)=W(0)$ and $X=W(0)$, leaving no room for inference for $B$.

**Analytically**, however, from the above expression, in the limit of $\delta\downarrow0$,  $\mathbb{P}(B=1|X)=0$, suggesting that I should always infer that $B=0$.

So what is the correct result? Can I infer anything about $B$ in the limit of $\delta\downarrow0$?

Comment: But the expected size of $X^2$ will also shrink as $\delta \rightarrow 0$. For $X \sim W(\delta), \mathbb{E}(X^2) = Var(X) = \delta$ and for $X \sim W(2\delta), \mathbb{E}(X^2) = Var(X) = 4\delta$. So $\mathbb{P}(B = 1 \mid X)$ will still depend on whether $X^2$ is large compared to $\delta$.

Comment: I made a mistake above: for $X \sim W(2\delta), \mathbb{E}(X^2) = 2\delta$.

Comment: Right, $\mathbb{E}[X^2]=\delta$ or $2\delta$. That is, **on average**, the size of $X$ is shrinking too. But for any **realization** of $X$, the above derivation is correct, I guess?

Comment: Thanks for asking the follow-up question. I've tried to give a full answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The probability $$\mathbb{P}(B = 1 \mid X) = \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}e^{X^2/(4\delta)}}$$ only depends on $X$ and $\delta$ through the term $X^2/(4\delta)$. Now let's think about the cases when $B = 1$ or $B = 0$.

When $B = 1$ then $X \sim N(0, \delta)$, so $X/\sqrt{\delta} \sim N(0, 1)$. Therefore $X^2/\delta \sim \chi^2_1$, a [chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution). And $X^2/(4\delta) \sim \chi^2_1/4$, the distribution of a $\chi^2_1$ random variable divided by $4$.

When $B = 0$ then $X \sim N(0, 2\delta)$, so $X/\sqrt{2\delta} \sim N(0, 1)$. Therefore $X^2/(2\delta) \sim \chi^2_1$, and $X^2/(4\delta) \sim \chi^2_1/2$, the distribution of a $\chi^2_1$ random variable divided by $2$.

In either case, the distribution of $X^2/(4\delta)$ does not depend on $\delta$. So as $\delta \rightarrow 0$, $\mathbb{P}(B = 1\mid X)$ does not tend to any particular limit.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Alex. This is very clear for the conclusion that "the distribution of $X^2/(4\delta)$ does not depend on $\delta$". But I guess in evaluating $\mathbb{P}(B=1|X)$, it is the realization of $X$ that matters (as opposed to its distribution)?

Comment: I agree, what I'm saying is that $\mathbb{P}(B = 1 \mid X)$ is not dependent on $\delta$. For any value of $\delta$ the probability that $B = 1$ given $X$ just depends on whether the realization of $X^2/(4\delta)$ is larger or smaller than we would expect if $B = 1$. As $\delta \downarrow 0$, nothing of interest happens to the probability we will assign to the event $B = 1$.

Comment: Thanks again, Alex. Very much appreciated. So I think I see the issue much clearer now but I am still not so sure of the conclusion you hinted above. Indeed, fixing any value of $\delta$, $\mathbb{P}(B=1|X)$ just depends on the realization of $X^2/\delta$. So as I take the limit of $\delta\downarrow0$, the realization of $X^2/\delta$ explodes to infinity (for any $|X|\neq0$) and this affects $\mathbb{P}(B=1|X)$, no?

Comment: Sure, if you *fix* $X \neq 0$ then $X^2/\delta \rightarrow \infty$ and $\mathbb{P}(B = 1 \mid X) \rightarrow 0$ as $\delta \downarrow 0$. I assumed you were talking about calculating $\mathbb{P}(B = 1 \mid X)$ when $X=BW(\delta)+(1−B)W(2\delta)$. So if you were thinking about this probability as $\delta \downarrow 0$, you would need a sequence of $\delta$s $\delta_0, \delta_1, \dots$ that converges down to $0$, and for each $\delta_i$ you need a new random variable $X_i =BW(\delta_i)+(1−B)W(2\delta_i)$. Then the sequence of $\mathbb{P}(B = 1 \mid X_i)$ realizations will not tend to a limit.

Comment: Compare with the Weak Law of Large Numbers, where a probability depends on a constant $n$ and converges to $1$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Weak_law